# Does disabling mobile data when I'm connected to wi-fi conserve battery?

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life, mobile-data, nexus-5x

I always do this out of habit, but it recently occurred to me that Android might be clever enough to automatically turn it off when I've got wi-fi access. Is it?

Comment: eh @beeshyams – missing a "no" somewhere? :)

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to WiFi automatically disables mobile data on most phones, so turning it off manually does not save your battery. There are some phones which have a "turbo download" mode, that uses both WiFi and data to download files faster, however most phones don't have it.